# SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO Join model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

In my model, projects have and belong to many users, so there is a join table projects_users for them.  When I insert the line

```
@project.members += User.find params[:member_ids].split(',')
```

into the create action of the Projects controller, I cannot save @project.  When I try, I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "projects_users" ("project_id", "user_id") VALUES (5, 14600)
```

However, just before the save, @project is valid and @project.members returns the correct members.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a unique constraint on the DB column that doesn't allow duplicate `project_id` and `user_id` pairs in `projects_users`, but Rails isn't aware of it, so the validations pass, but the actual save fails.

If that's the case, you can use a `has_many` `through` relationship and a model for the join table and validate the uniqueness.  I suspect you're already doing part of that of that.  Something like this might help:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :project_membership
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, through: :project_membership
end

class ProjectMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "projects_users"
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  validates :project_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

You might want to rename your `projects_users` table if this all works out, to something like `project_memberships` as in the example above; then you could ditch the `self.table_name`.

Comment: How could I find out about a unique constraint on the db?  I looked at the migration and schema and did not see this constraint, nor did I specify it anywhere.  Beyond that, I am not inserting duplicate project_id and user_id pairs, every user_id is unique.

Comment: Although I don't understand what constraint I violated, this answer does work.  It seems HABTM relationships are being increasingly less supported in Rails.